# I got this error: Unhandled exception at 0x5B4EFB53 (msvcr120d.dll) in myfirstproject.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC

Tags: c

I am currently working on a quiz program that is configurable from a text file. The problem comes when I try to make the program to only print array 0 to 3. Sorry if my question is a noob-ish question. I'm new to C. What's wrong with my code?

UPDATE:

The code works after array[i++] is changed to array[j++]. For the first loop, it works fine. But the next loop, the data stored inside the arrays seem to be messed up. I edited the testingc.txt content too just to test the new random that is suggested by Paul Ogilvie.

First Output:

```
This is the first question
A.Really
B.No
C.Yes
```

After I put in C as the answer, it prints Correct! and the marks. But for the next loop, it gives this output:

```
Which one of this is an OS

s 10
B.Microsoft Word
```

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    //Variables
    int i, linepick, line = 1, found = 0, marks = 0, j = 0;
    char chars[1000], answer[1000], questionfile[] = "C:\\Users\\cbtcode\\Desktop\\testingc.txt";

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(questionfile, "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Can't find question file.\n");
    }
    else {
    while (fgets(chars, 1000, file)) 
    {
        linepick = rand() % 20 + 1;
        for (i = 0; i < linepick; i++) 
        {
            if (fgets(chars, 1000, file) == NULL)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                found = 1;
                char *p;
                char *array[1000];

                p = strtok(chars, ";"); 
                while (p != NULL) 
                {
                    array[j++] = p;
                    p = strtok(NULL, ";");
                }
                if (array != NULL)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", array[0]);
                    printf("%s\n", array[1]);
                    printf("%s\n", array[2]);
                    printf("%s\n", array[3]);
                    scanf("%s", answer);

                    if (strcmp(answer, array[4]) == 0) {
                        printf("Correct!\n");
                        marks = marks + 10;
                        printf("Your Marks: %d%%\n\n", marks);
                    }
                    else {
                        printf("Wrong!\n");
                        marks = marks - 10;
                        printf("Your Marks: %d%%\n\n", marks);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("ERROR: Can't find the question!");
                }
            }
        }
        line++;
    }
    if (found == 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Line number %d was not found.", linepick);
    }
}
```

My testingc.txt content:

```
This is the first question;A.Really;B.No;C.Yes;C;
This is the first question;A.Really;B.No;C.Yes;C;
Which one of these is an OS;A.Windows 10;B.Microsoft Word;C.Notepad;C;
```

Comment: It's crashing. Use a debugger.

Comment: You probably tried to dereference a pointer (that means accessing the thing it points to) when it doesn't actually point to anything meaningful.

Comment: Storing pointers to tokens parsed with strtok() seems dodgy to me....(?)

Comment: You also have a problem: `linepick` might be used before it is given a value. For example, what if the file is empty? `fgets()` will return `NULL` immediately, and `linepick` will have an undefined value.

Comment: in your modified code, if you are initializing j at the start of main, then you need to initialize to 0 before entering  `while (p != NULL)` . Hope you understood the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the below piece of code:

```
            while (p != NULL) 
            {
                array[i++] = p;
                p = strtok(NULL, ";");
            }
            printf("%s\n", array[0]);
            printf("%s\n", array[1]);
            printf("%s\n", array[2]);
            printf("%s\n", array[3]);
            scanf("%s", answer);

            if (strcmp(answer, array[4]) == 0) {
                printf("Correct!\n");
                marks = marks + 10;
                printf("Your Marks: %d%%\n", marks);
            }
```

How do you know that you have array[1], array[2],  array[3],  array[4] etc are assigned in the loop. 
You did not check before accessing them. If they are not assigned they will have garbage value because you have not initialized array.

Also, you are doing `array[i++] = p;`.
May be you need to use a different counter j.

**Edit based on OP's request:**
Try this code:

```
       if (linepick == line) 
        {
            found = 1;
            char *p = NULL;
            char *array[1000] = {NULL};
            int j = -1, k = 0;

            p = strtok(chars, ";"); 
            while (p != NULL) 
            {
                j += 1:
                array[j] = p;
                p = strtok(NULL, ";");
            }
            if ( j >= 0 ) {
                for (k=0; k < j && k < 4; k++) {
                    printf("%s\n", array[k]);

                scanf("%s", answer);

                if (j >= 4 && array[4] && (strcmp(answer, array[4]) == 0)) {
                    printf("Correct!\n");
                    marks = marks + 10;
                    printf("Your Marks: %d%%\n", marks);
                }
                else {
                    printf("Wrong!\n");
                    marks = marks - 10;
                    printf("Your Marks: %d%%\n", marks);
                }
            }
            else {
                printf("Wrong!\n");
                marks = marks - 10;
                printf("Your Marks: %d%%\n", marks);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing the array[i++] part. I forgot that I made counter j for that array. What do you mean by checking them before accessing them?

Comment: if you use j and initialize it to 0 before the loop, you will know, whether the strtok entered the loop and assigned the value. That is you need to check if (j > 0) only then you need to print and use strcmp. i.e, for array[0] to array[j] you can print and use strcmp.

Comment: Other way to do is initialize *array[1000] with NULL. Check whether they are NULL or not after the loop before printing and before doing strcmp.

Comment: You can initialize like this `char *array[1000] = {NULL}:`

Comment: I made the check part that you suggest. But now I'm facing a new kind of problem. The first loop is works fine. But when it comes for the next loop, the array is messed up. What happen?

Comment: you should show the modified code

Comment: @cbtcode I have modified that block for you. Check it now.

Comment: It gives a different output. This is the ouput:                                       `This is the first question
C
Correct!
Your Marks: 10%
A.Really
B
Wrong!
Your Marks: 0%`

Comment: for that I need to have testingc.txt. I don't know what logic you have used. My job was only to rectify the `accessviolation` error. Raise a new question with your testingc.txt data or atleast 1 or 2 lines of example of that data.

Comment: The code is now fixed. Thanks Sri.U

Answer (score 0):

The loop `for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)` reparses `chars` 20 multiples times.

The second time, no `;` are present in the array anymore because they have all been replaced with `'\0'` by `strtok`.

Hence `strtok` returns `chars`, and `array[i++] = p;` stores `p` beyond the end of the array.

This is **Undefined behavior**. Anything can happen: for example, since you repeat this multiple times, you might overwrite critical data on the stack, causing the crash you observe.

**UPDATE**:

Editing the code posted in a question is problematic, it makes the comments and answers inconsistent.  Consider asking a new question if you experience more problems after fixing the initial issues from the answer provided.

You still have issues in the updated code:

- You do not initialize `j` before the parsing loop.  The first line will be stored into the array correctly if it does not contain more `;` than there are entries in `array`, but subsequent lines will be parsed into out of bounds positions.
- Your test for correct parsing is incorrect: `array` is never `NULL`, it is an array in automatic storage, not a pointer.  You should instead check if 5 fields have been parsed with `if (j == 5)`.
- Your attempt to shuffle the questions does not work very well, you should rewind the stream before each try and use an array to avoid asking the same question more than once.  The current implementation is confused and always skips the first line.

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int i, n, total_lines, marks = 0;
    char chars[1000], answer[10];
    char questionfile[] = "C:\\Users\\cbtcode\\Desktop\\testingc.txt";
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen(questionfile, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open question file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // first determine the number of questions:
    for (total_lines = 0; fgets(chars, sizeof(chars), file) != NULL;) {
        strtok(chars, ";");     // question
        strtok(NULL, ";");      // A choice
        strtok(NULL, ";");      // B choice
        strtok(NULL, ";");      // C choice
        if (strtok(NULL, ";")) {  // correct choice.
            total_lines++;
        }
    }
    if (total_lines == 0) {
        printf("No valid questions in the file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // ask at most total_lines unique questions
    int asked[total_lines];
    for (i = 0; i < total_lines; i++)
        asked[i] = 0;

    for (n = 0; n < total_lines; n++) {
        int skip = rand() % (total_lines - n);
        rewind(file);
        for (i = 0; fgets(chars, 1000, file) != NULL;) {
            char *array[5];
            array[0] = strtok(chars, ";");  // question
            array[1] = strtok(NULL, ";");   // A choice
            array[2] = strtok(NULL, ";");   // B choice
            array[3] = strtok(NULL, ";");   // C choice
            array[4] = strtok(NULL, ";");   // correct choice.
            if (array[4] == NULL)  // invalid line
                continue;
            if (asked[i++])        // question asked already
                continue;
            if (skip-- > 0)        // skip this question
                continue;
            asked[i] = 1;
            printf("%s\n", array[0]);
            printf("%s\n", array[1]);
            printf("%s\n", array[2]);
            printf("%s\n", array[3]);
            if (scanf("%9s", answer) != 1) {
                printf("premature end of file\n");
                return 1;
            }
            if (strcmp(answer, array[4]) == 0) {
                printf("Correct!\n");
                marks = marks + 10;
                printf("Your Marks: %d%%\n\n", marks);
            } else {
                printf("Wrong!\n");
                marks = marks - 10;
                printf("Your Marks: %d%%\n\n", marks);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    printf("Your final score: %d%%\n\n", marks);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works after I changed the i to j. It works fine for the first loop. But when it loops for the second time, the array messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of comments to be made, but the cause is your

```
array[i++] = p;
```

because `i` is also your loop counter so it can have any value up to 20. Then, if you want to print elements 0..3 these are probably null pointers and so you access memory that is not yours: access violation.

Use a new variable, e.g. `int j` to index the array.

--EDIT--

OK, so you fixed this error. The next error is that you read one question, then loop 20 times until `linepick == line` but...the question hasn't changed so you always show the same question. You probably want to read a question that matches the randomly chosen `linepick`, so you must read `linepick` lines, roughly:

```
    linepick = rand() % 20; 
    for (i = 0; i < linepick; i++)
    { 
         if (fgets(chars, 1000, file)==NULL) break;  // no such question
         ...
```

Comment: I forgot about the counter j i made is for the array. Thank you!